# Why can I invoke a function guarded with instanceof but not typeof?

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```
let x: Record<string, string> | Function = {};

if (x instanceof Function) {
    x();
}

if (typeof x === "function") {
    x();
}
```

The first invocation guarded with `instanceof` works, but the second guarded with `typeof` produces this error:

> This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures.

When can a variable's type be evaluated to `function` but still not be callable?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBBKIDGB7ATgEwDwGcxoEsA7AcwBoI9DSA%20CAHwgDEBXIpMAlIiAXggDeAXwDcAKDEEAZhAAUUCMTwBDdiBQzW7TtwCUgsRCPRZu8UInS5YAJ4AHdTIW8XEAERS2HLkTf6BhsZQpuZiQA)

Comment: It's interesting that, when hovering over `x` in conditionals, TypeScript shows the type as `Record<string, string>`, not the union. If we change variable to the external declaration, everything works - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gDwFzwCVwkZgAeTGASxQHMAaeSm2gPngB94AxAVxTAYqqANwAoMVQBm8ABTZ4NTFAEgkMvgKGoAlPADeY+MZyyd4gL4TpcjAE8ADmpkKAvO-gAiKf0HCUnnqGJqbmYlZAA.

Comment: If we use it as argument to function, it works too - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgB4C5EBKKEcATgCYA8GpMYA5gDSI130B8iAPogGLjR4YAJSIA3gChE0xDGCIcssBgCGkFHHn9IsBKMkzDibJmEBuKTIC+Ey9LkKoATwAOG+dkQBeH4gBEoDpCfvp2RibmYTY2QA.

Comment: I mostly know what's going on here but there are a few weird things interacting and I want to be sure you're really trying to ask this question as-is. Union-typed variables like `x` get narrowed via control flow analysis upon assignment, so as soon as you write `let x: Record<string, string> | Function = {}` the compiler has already narrowed it to `Record<string, string>` since `{}` is certainly not a function.  After that you get differing behavior because of how the compiler does control flow narrowing with `instanceof` vs `typeof`; one's an intersection, the other's a union filter.

Comment: So, do you really intend to ask it this way?  If you wrote `let x: string | number = "hello"; if (typeof x === "number") {x.toFixed()}` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7gDrN) you get a similar problem.  It has nothing to do with functions and everything to do with control-flow narrowing of an impossible situation; it's sort of implementation dependent whether the compiler notices that it's impossible and complains (`never` has no properties) or fails to notice it's impossible and is fine with it.

Comment: @jcalz Interesting - can you point me in the direction of a reference that explains the intersectio vs union filter differentation? Based on your comments, I updated the assignment to `let x: Record<string, string> | Function = Math.random() > 0.5 ? {} : () => "foo";` and the compiler no longer throws an error there is no longer a definite narrowing.

Comment: I'm not sure there exists a canonical reference, since these are compiler details so probably it's a bunch of GitHub issues and TS compiler source code.  If you edit the question so as to specifically ask about that I might be able to pull that together into an answer.  But currently this really feels like a corner case to me, and it might not be particularly illuminating to understand exactly when the compiler decides to narrow via union filtering vs intersecting.

Comment: @jcalz we don't need to get that far into the weeds, this is indeed a corner case that simply piqued my curiosity. Knowing the behaviour is effected due to assignment narrowing is enough for me. Thanks for your input.